# Sort NumPy array by values in two columns

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

So I've a 2d array, that when sorted by the second column using `a[np.argsort(-a[:,1])]` looks like this:

```
array([[ 30.        ,  98.7804878 ],
       [ 24.        ,  98.7804878 ],
       [ 21.        ,  98.7804878 ],
       [ 26.        ,  98.7804878 ],
       [ 20.        ,  98.70875179],
       [  4.        ,  98.27833572],
       [  1.        ,   7.10186514]])
```

Now I want to sort this by the lowest "id" column so it looks like this:

```
array([[ 21.        ,  98.7804878 ],
       [ 24.        ,  98.7804878 ],
       [ 26.        ,  98.7804878 ],
       [ 30.        ,  98.7804878 ],
       [ 20.        ,  98.70875179],
       [  4.        ,  98.27833572],
       [  1.        ,   7.10186514]])
```

I can't figure out how to do it, even if I take the top highest percentages from the first and then order them.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`np.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) for this:

```
>>> a[np.lexsort((a[:, 0], -a[:, 1]))]
array([[ 21.        ,  98.7804878 ],
       [ 24.        ,  98.7804878 ],
       [ 26.        ,  98.7804878 ],
       [ 30.        ,  98.7804878 ],
       [ 20.        ,  98.70875179],
       [  4.        ,  98.27833572],
       [  1.        ,   7.10186514]])
```

This sorts by `-a[:, 1]`, then by `a[:, 0]`, returning an array of indices than you can use to index `a`.